# « Je suis descendue » vs « j’ai descendu »

Tags: grammaire, auxiliaires

Pour le verbe « descendre », quand on utilise le passé composé, quel auxiliaire on peut choisir? *être* ou *avoir*?

Par exemple :

1. *Je suis descendue du train.* C’est un COI, non? C’est pourquoi un COI suit le participé passé?
2. *J’ai descendu l’escalier de l'immeuble.* C’est un COD, non? C’est pourquoi un COD suit le participé passé?

Et plus, les escaliers et l'escalier, c'est pareil?

Comment: Escalier justifie une question séparée. *Un escalier* c'est l'ensemble des marches qui permettent de passer d'un niveau à l'autre. En langage **populaire**,  *escaliers* est parfois utilisé pour désigner l’ensemble de la cage d'escalier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Descendre

Pour la première question, *descendre* a des sens différents selon sa construction. Grosso modo, *descendre* intransitif (avec *être* et un complément indirect) met l'accent sur le fait de quitter un lieu "élevé": on descend d'un toit, d'un animal que l'on monte (et apr extension d'un véhicule), d'une échelle, d'une montagne...

D'un autre côté, dans sa construction transitive (avec *avoir* et un complément direct), *descendre*, outre son sens d'"abattre avec une arme à feu", met plutôt l'accent sur la "surface" sur laquelle le sujet se déplace: on descend un escalier, une rivière, une pente...

Il y a une certaine variations dans la construction (toujours intransitive, que je sache) avec *avoir* ou *être* de certains verbes. Toutefois les verbes de mouvement comme *descendre* présentent rarement cette variation, qui est beaucoup plus présente dans les composés de *paraître*, tout particulièrement *apparaître* et *disparaître*.

### Escalier

À mon sens, *escalier* au pluriel est un peu un nom collectif qui sous-entend généralement l'ensemble des escaliers d'un bâtiment.

Au singulier, soit on parle d'un escalier ou d'une cage d'escalier précise, soit à tout le moins une volée de marche précise entre deux étages.

Si quelqu'un "a dévalé les escaliers à toute vitesse", cela implique donc pour moi qu'il a descendu au moins deux étages.

Answer (score 5):

On peut donner deux explications pour justifier l'emploi de *être* ou *avoir* pour former les temps composés de *descendre*.

Une d'abord très simplifiée qui peut servir à quelqu'un qui débute dans l'apprentissage du français :
Quand il est **transitif** (construit avec un COD) *descendre* se construit avec **avoir** aux temps composés :

> J'ai descendu l'escalier.

Quand il est **intransitif** (sans complément ou avec un COI) *descendre* se construit avec **être** aux temps composés :

> Je suis descendu(e).
> Je suis descendu(e) par l'escalier.

Cette explication donnée aux apprenants les empêche de commettre des erreurs mais elle est incomplète car en fait on peut aussi parfois utiliser *avoir* quand *descendre* est intransitif.

Une explication donnée par [l'Académie](http://books.google.fr/books?id=OQ8JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA525&lpg=PA525&dq=%22%20Il%20a%20descendu%20bien%20promptement%22&source=bl&ots=0fULgwDlAp&sig=PfaHgQ8MxXWFEan-xBIbsjF_eGE&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=70hTVM2lD4KNaKuIgaAE&ved=0CEUQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22%20Il%20a%20descendu%20bien%20promptement%22&f=false) est de dire que *descendre* se conjugue avec *être* quand il désigne le **résultat d'une action** et avec *avoir ou être* quand il désigne une **action**.

On considère le résultat d'une action :

> Il est descendu. (Ce qui m'intéresse c'est qu'il est maintenant en bas)

On considère l'action :

> Il a descendu bien promptement.
>
> Il est descendu bien promptement.

Comment: « Il a enlevé sa petite chemise, son petit couplet ses p’tits souliers. Il est descendu l’escalier en me laissant une épaule démise. » – Boris Vian. Mais j’avoue que ça m’étonne à chaque fois que je l’entends.

Comment: @Édouard Cet emploi de descendre par Boris Vian est très personnel et fait partie de la licence poétique qui permet tout. Le poète peut se permettre des tournures qu'il vaut mieux par ailleurs déconseiller aux apprenants car ils ne pourraient pas les justifier.

Comment: Ne voulais-tu pas dire qu'on peut utiliser \*avoir\* losque l'emploi est intransitif?

Comment: Oui, bien sûr.  on peut aussi parfois utiliser *avoir* quand descendre est intransitif, sinon ça ne veut rien dire. Merci de la correction.