# Verbes de mouvement conjugués avec être et avoir : pourquoi cette différence ?

Tags: conjugaison, auxiliaires, évolution, temps-composés

On apprend que plusieurs verbes de mouvement font partie du groupe des verbes conjugués avec l'auxiliaire *être* aux temps composés.

> Sortir, descendre, aller, passer (par ou devant), tomber, arriver,
>   entrer, retourner, revenir, monter, rentrer, rester, venir, devenir,
>   partir, repartir, ressortir.

Je me demande pourquoi d'autres verbes de mouvement incluant :

> sauter, courir, marcher, cheminer, trotter, trottiner, patiner, avancer, reculer, bondir, rebondir, tourner, enjamber, sautiller, pivoter, etc.

sont conjugués avec *avoir* ou, équivalemment, pourquoi les verbes du premier ensemble sont conjugués avec *être*.

Comment: [J'ai descendu l'escalier](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12194/je-suis-descendue-vs-j-ai-descendu), je suis bien avancé...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'emploi des verbes être et avoir est abordé dans la [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_auxiliaire) ; ce qui suit est l'essentiel de ce qu'elle enseigne, un résumé répondant partiellement à la question.

Il y a trois catégories de constructions avec un auxiliaire : une avec « avoir » (tous les transitifs et la majorité des intransitifs), une avec « être » (tous les pronominaux et quelques intransitifs), une avec les deux ; il y a un grand nombre de verbes dans la première, peu dans la seconde et ceux de la troisième sont rares.

Les verbes de mouvements ne sont pas exactement reconnus comme une classe dans l'article de la Wikipédia et font partie du petit nombre des verbes intransitifs se conjuguant avec « être », tous des verbes très courants ; l'ensemble est caractérisé comme composé de verbe de **mouvement et de changement** *ou* **transformation** à l'exception de « **demeurer** » et « **rester** » qui, bizarrement  « ont pu être conjugués avec avoir jusqu'au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle » ; presque tous sont des verbes **perfectifs**.

> Une vingtaine de verbes seulement composent ce groupe.
>
> - aller,
> - venir et ses composés dont devenir,
> - arriver,
> - (re)partir,
> - (r)entrer,
>     -(re)sortir,
> - (re)monter,
> - (re)descendre,
> - (re)tomber,
> - naître,
> - mourir,
> - décéder,
> - demeurer,
> - rester

Selon cet article il faut retenir qu'il n'existe pas de théorie unique de l'usage de l'auxiliaire « être ». Mon opinion personnelle est qu'il n'existe pas de théorie qui permette de discriminer parmi les verbes de mouvement quant à ceux pour lesquels il faut un auxiliaire plutôt que l'autre sinon elle serait souvent mentionnée à l'apprenant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91224/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-verbes-de-mouvement-conjugues-avec-etre-et-avoir-p).